# Dataflow streaming - does it fit our use case?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We've been using Dataflow in batch mode for a while now. However, we can't seem to find much info on its streaming mode.

We have a the following use case:

- Data/events are being streamed real-time into BigQuery
- We need to transform/clean/denormalize the data before analysis by
  the business

Now, we could of course use Dataflow in batch mode, and take chucks of the data from BigQuery (based on timestamps), and transform/clean/denormalize it that way.

But that's a bit of a messy approach, especially because data is being streamed real-time and it will probably get real gnarly working out which data needs to be worked on. Sounds brittle too.

It would be great if we could simply transform/clean/denormalize in Dataflow, and then write to BigQuery **as it's streaming in**.

Is this what Dataflow streaming is intended for? If so, what data source can Dataflow read from in streaming mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a very reasonable use case for streaming mode. Currently we support reading from [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) via the `PubsubIO` source.  Additional sources are in the works. Output can be written to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) via the `BigQueryIO` sink. The [`PCollection` docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pcollection) cover the distinction between bounded and unbounded sources/sinks, as well as the currently available concrete implementations.

As to any apparent lack of streaming-specific documentation, the majority of the unified model is applicable in batch and streaming, so there is no streaming-specific section. That said, I'd recommend looking over the [Windowing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing) and [Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers) sections of the `PCollection` docs, as those are particularly applicable when dealing with unbounded `PCollection`s.

Comment: So, it would be something like this: ping endpoint with event -> pub/sub -> Dataflow (in streaming mode) -> BigQuery. Sound about right?!